# how to: Please sudo, do _not_ setup any environment, especially $SUDO_USER?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

I want to start a process as another `uid` and it should not need any information from `$(env)`, so I strip the environment prior to the `sudo -u powerlessuser /bin/processCmd`, that is I run this

```
env -i sudo -u powerlessuser /bin/processCmd
```

it turns out sudo thinks it is necessary to repopulate the environment, which I would like to ask it not to do. There is for instance `$SUDO_USER` set which even tells the `powerlessuser`'s `/bin/processCmd` about me(tm) that called the command, which I find very indiscrete. Any help?

It is as I figured also possible to use `env -i` stripping after the sudo, i.e. do this:

```
sudo -u powerlessuser /usr/bin/env -i /bin/processCmd
```

which solves the problem somewhat, yet I would really like to know if there is a way to make `sudo` not add any information in the first place, I browsed [man 8 sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) in which I found documentation that `sudo` adds environment and which, but no help how to make `sudo` not do that

@terdon♦: I want all environment variables cleaned that are not necessary. I am unable to tell which environmental variables are necessary but just to stick to the question, I have not found the reason why `$SUDO_USER` would be needed by a process to be called as an unpriveledged user. Therefore I would be satisfied to know how to tell `sudo` not to leak `SUDO_USER`

*Update* - xy-problem issue

As much as I am very interested in avoiding anything of the kind of a xy-problem, I fear it is not the case here. That is because, I do not have actually a different problem as the one stated in the question, namely that *searching a way to make sudo not do something*, which I can reasonably expect: Sudo get an cleaned up environment and should at best not add stuff to it, i.e. `$SUDO_USER`. For this reason I am rather very convinced not to have any other problem, since I have already a cure to that issue that `sudo` leaves me with, i.e. I can do:

```
sudo -u powerlessuser /usr/bin/env -i /bin/processCmd
```

which "cleans up after sudo", so in no way is my problem something else, because using the subsequent `env -i` solved any problem there. The only thing I ask is for knowing if there would have been indeed a way like 
`sudo --empty-env` which then would spawn the new process with an emptied environment, one that at least would not tell `$SUDO_USER` which `uid` ran the original `sudo`.

For all that showed interest in helping me with this question, I like to thank them! I also leave some time, maybe there is such a `--empty-env` switch possibility. If not maybe somebody that is inside of `sudo` can tell, i.e. with reference to the sources that such a task is impossible, as sudo cannot but put that undesired `$SUDO_USER` inside.

Again no xy-problem, for the fact, that it is not really a problem to start with, i.e I do not suffer from the shortcomings of `sudo` here, as it is solved by a subsequent `env -i`, which in "unix philosophy" is the one thing that `env -i` does well, i.e. clean the environment. I should maybe not even have expected any reasonable behavior from `sudo` there, as sudo has a different one-purpose, which is not concerned about environment variables leaking. Even though, the fact that `sudo` does offer some flags relating to environment variables misleads into thinking it would deal with environment variables well.

Comment: Does `sudo -E` help?

Comment: @Pandya nice idea :). surely the preserve environment flag would not be the first comming to mind, if I explicitly intend to **not** preserve it. Still given that I `env -i` cleaned the environment, I would like to *preserve a clean environment*. I tried it and still `sudo` is *poluting* my `$(env)` with `$SUDO_USER`. What does this yield to you? `env -i sudo -E  /bin/printenv`

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28216373#28216373

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what variables you don't want to see exported. Some have to be set, do you just want them to be set to the environment that `powerlessuser` would get on login?

Comment: @terdon. I have edited the question. I will have to get some knowledge about which environment variables are absolutely needed. I think people think some are needed, when indeed they are simpy useful, I have myself writen lots of programs that never ever used -at least explicitly- any information form the environment. Anyway as edited to the question, not leaking `SUDO_USER` would be a great start

Comment: I doubt that's possible since that is set by `sudo` itself and has nothing to do with the parent shell's environment. This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Could you [edit] your question and explain what your final objective is? `sudo` might not even be the right tool for the job.

Comment: @tendon, without wanting to make this a lengthy comment discussion, I think it is best to state here once more what I think is already inside of the question. I do not want `$SUDO_USER` being set by `sudo` in the environment. I think that is reasonable to ask, since it is totally sudo that does it and I thought, there might be a flag to keep it from doing it. So my goal is to not have sudo add stuff to my environment. Since being invoked after a `env -i` it finds an clean environment and should not polute that. I think that is reasonable to ask. `sudo` has no reason to dirty my env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tool does not do what you want, you can improve it using a wrapper script.  I use this script ([`noenv`](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:noenv)) to keep build environments clean.  Using it like

```
sudo -u powerlessuser noenv /bin/processCmd
```

would do what you're asking.  (The script should be in the standard path, otherwise you have to provide it path in the command).

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: noenv,v 1.3 2014/05/10 22:43:32 tom Exp $
# trim the environment to minimal (PATH may still be long...)
env | sed -e 's/=.*//' -e '/^[  ].*/d' | \
while true
do
    read value
    if test -z "$value" ; then
        # honor assignments to variables in the parameter list
        while test $# != 0
        do
            case "x$1" in
            *=*)
                eval $1
                name=`echo "$1"|sed -e 's/=.*//'`
                export $name
                shift 1
                ;;
            *)
                break
                ;;
            esac
        done
        exec "$@"
        break
    fi
    case "$value" in
    HOME|PATH|USER|_|SHLVL|TMPDIR|LOGNAME)
        ;;
    *\ *|*\(*|*\)*|*\!*)
        #echo "...skipping $value"
        ;;
    *)
        #echo value:"$value"
        unset "$value"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

To clarify, I did not write this using `/usr/bin/env`, because some of the systems on which I was building did not have a POSIX feature which the question mentioned: the `-i` option.  Those are old BSD systems, including [SunOS 4](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=env&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%204.1.3&arch=default&format=html) and [HPUX 10](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=env&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=HP-UX%2010.20&arch=default&format=html) (checking my memory against the manual page for "env" on FreeBSD).

The script, by the way, trims out multi-line values (but the only one you might encounter is `TERMCAP`, and that only on very old machines).  The second sed-expression is supposed to be a range with <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.

For POSIX (which you probably are more interested in), you could do something that uses the feature to pass in selected values from the parent environment, e.g.,

```
env -i foo="bar"
```

and so both are customizable.  For a large set of variables, that can be clumsy, and a script is a better choice.

`sudo` disapproves of `TERMCAP` in any case.  That is on a (long) list of variables which it helpfully removes from the environment.

`sudo` insists on setting certain variables.  Reading the source [`plugins/sudoers/env.c`](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/271c6738213d/plugins/sudoers/env.c), you will see this chunk near the end of `rebuild_env`:

```
/* Add the SUDO_USER, SUDO_UID, SUDO_GID environment variables. */
CHECK_SETENV2("SUDO_USER", user_name, true, true);
snprintf(idbuf, sizeof(idbuf), "%u", (unsigned int) user_uid);
CHECK_SETENV2("SUDO_UID", idbuf, true, true);
snprintf(idbuf, sizeof(idbuf), "%u", (unsigned int) user_gid);
CHECK_SETENV2("SUDO_GID", idbuf, true, true);

debug_return_bool(true);
```

that is, just before the (only) successful return from that function, it sets its own *variables*, using its own *values*.

Comment: thank you for offering this script, much appreciated!  Yet in relation to the question, the answer is that with `sudo` alone one can not really have any flag that would set `sudo` to explicitly not include new stuff to the environment, especially `$SUDO_USER`, is that correct?

Comment: On a second note: How does the solution you offer differ from the one I included in the question itself `sudo -u powerless env -i /bin/processCmd`, that is, do you think that your noenv is favourable over `env -i`?

Comment: Mine is customizable (and portable).

Comment: Agree: `sudo` does not appear to provide the feature you want.

Comment: thank you for this clarification. If you can substantiate, that sudo has no way of getting its "I do not leave some unwanted environment variables like $SUDO_USER"-shit together, then you could add that to your answer for me to accept it. Or maybe somebody else is able to supply such evidence in another answer. thank you also for pointing out the customizability thing. I also think it is great that you solution might be not relying on `/usr/bin/env` to exist, though I think one could

Comment: Great job enriching the answer with a reference to the sudo source, which settles the question, to it being impossible (least changing the source and compile yourself) to get sudo to refrain from adding `$SUDO_USER`. Anyway with the insight given into `env` also in your answer nobody would need to go into the trouble changing the source. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to unset only specific env vars, like SUDO_USER, you can filter them out when calling sudo by using the 'env -u ' option.

For example,

```
sudo -u powerless env -u SUDO_USER -u SUDO_UID ./some_script.sh
```

unsets SUDO_USER and SUDO_UID in the environment which runs the script ./some_script.sh.

Note the order, since -u has different meaning when it follows sudo vs. env.