# How can I make sudo discard all environment variables?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

People usually want to preserve their environment variables while executing `sudo` for various reasons, but, there are some cases where discarding environment variables makes much more sense. For example, on Ubuntu, `$HOME` (along with a few other variables) is carried over to the process spawned as root; however, this makes no sense when trying to use Linux containers.

One could obviously edit `/etc/sudoers` to configure this behaviour, but I'd like to keep this behaviour and resort to discarding environment variables only for certain commands. There is a `-H` flag, but that is only for `$HOME` and doesn't really help in my case since I need to unset *all* variables.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Just to clarify, env_reset is not enough? http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html -- "This causes commands to be executed with a new, minimal environment."

Comment: PATH could be useful, unless you want to fully-path such commands...

Comment: Strongly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269509/117549

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the dash as in:

```
sudo su - me
```

That way you run in *me*'s environment and not the environment you come from.

Comment: Oh, I went a little too fast I guess. You want to start `su`, but you need `sudo` in order to do that... (at least under Debian, Ubuntu...)